# What's this graph? (8 vertices, 16 edges)

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E) =$

```
f------g
|`.    |`.
|  `a--+---b
|   |  |   |
e---+--h   |
 `. |   `. |  .
   `d------c
```

Now let $G' = (V,\, E \cup \{\{a,h\}, \{b,e\}, \{c,f\}, \{d,g\}\})$. That's $G$ with 4 additional edges connecting the diagonals.

Is there a name for $G'$? Or, even better, is there a place I can go to look up graphs based on their properties?

Comment: Your ascii art ability is impressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G'$ would be the complete bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$ with bipartition $(\{a,c,e,g\}, \{b,d,f,h\})$.